# Capturing webview clicks (not just from links)

Tags: android, webview

Is there some way to set an onClickListener for a webview?  I've seen code here to intercept url clicks but I would just like to intercept anytime a user clicks the area the webview's on or swipes across it with their finger.  I load html directly into the webview (as opposed to giving it a url) for formatting reasons and I'd really like to be able to tell any time the user clicks anywhere on the screen.  I had been using a textview and that works fine, but is it doable with a webview?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried instead of an onClick, an onLongClick listener?

Taken from my recent project:

```
printMessageTextView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        int active = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
```

In this case, the int active = 0; is probably not needed. But should be able to listen for you.

Comment: if not, the public methods are listed here for you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html